# git reflog expire and git fsck --unreachable

Tags: git, reachability, reflog

Disclaimer: this question is purely informational and does not represent an actual problem I'm experiencing. I'm just trying to figure out stuff for the sake of it (because I love figuring stuff out, and I know you do too).

So I was playing with git, trying to expire an amended commit. My reflog looks like that:

```
4eea1cd HEAD@{0}: commit (amend): amend commit
ff576c1 HEAD@{1}: commit: test: bar
5a1e68a HEAD@{2}: commit: test: foo
da8534a HEAD@{3}: commit (initial): initial commit
```

Which means I made two commits (`da8534a` and `5a1e68a`), then a third commit `ff576c1` that I amended with `4eea1cd`.

Just as expected, my `git log` looks something like that:

```
* 4eea1cd (HEAD, master) amend commit
* 5a1e68a test: foo
* da8534a initial commit
```

From what I (though I) know about expirability of commits, some day (most likely, in 30 days by default) `git gc` should collect `ff576c1`. Now I don't want to wait for 30 days to see that happen, so I start running a few commands, first:

```
git fsck --unreachable --no-reflogs
```

Which, just as expected again, gives me:

```
unreachable blob 5716ca5987cbf97d6bb54920bea6adde242d87e6
unreachable tree 1e60e555e3500075d00085e4c1720030e077b6c8
unreachable commit ff576c1b4b6df57ba1c20afabd718c93dacf2fc6
```

All confident that I'm going to expire that poor lonely `ff576c1` commit, I then run `git reflog expire`:

```
git reflog expire --dry-run --expire-unreachable=now --all
```

Which, that time, gives me:

```
would prune commit: test: bar
would prune commit (amend): amend commit
```

At first I though my `HEAD` was not referencing `master`, but as you can see in the `git log` output I gave earlier, it actually does. Also, `cat .git/HEAD` confirms that (yelding `ref: refs/heads/master`). Anyway, even that though was silly, since `4eea1cd` is the head of my `master` branch.

So here I am, all confused that these two commands won't give me the same commits, and wondering how the hell could `4eea1cd` possibly be unreachable, since it's the actual tip of my `master` branch.

Any idea on what's going on?

**EDIT**: I just noticed if I add the `--rewrite` option to `git reflog expire`, like that:

```
git reflog expire --dry-run --expire-unreachable=now --all --rewrite
```

Then I only get the amended commit:

```
would prune commit: test: bar
```

I still don't understand, because according to `git help reflog`:

```
   --rewrite
       While expiring or deleting, adjust each reflog entry to ensure that
       the old sha1 field points to the new sha1 field of the previous
       entry.
```

Which doesn't make sense in my case. Well at least I don't get it, since obvisouly it **does** change something.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

This behavior comes from an interaction between the reflog design philosophy and the requirements of garbage collection.

For a commit to be safely deleted by the garbage collector, all references to that commit must be deleted—including references in reflog entries.  Despite the appearance of `reflog show`, each reflog entry actually contains two SHA1 identifiers:  the value of the ref before the change and the value of the ref after the change.  To ensure safe garbage collection, `reflog expire` simply deletes any entry where one of the two SHA1s identifies an unreachable commit.

In your case, the pre-change value of the most recent reflog entry refers to an unreachable commit.  Even though the commit identified by the post-change value is still reachable, `reflog expire` deletes the entry.

This design is simple to implement and results in an incomplete but accurate log.

#### the `--rewrite` option

Unfortunately, deleting an entry that refers to a still-reachable commit has a couple of problems:

- a gap is left in the log
- useful information related to still-reachable commits is lost

The `--rewrite` option addresses these problems by changing the behavior in the following way:

- As before, entries where the commit identified by the post-change SHA1 is unreachable are deleted.
- Entries where the pre-change commit is unreachable are modified to bridge the gap left by the deleted entry (the pre-change SHA1 is set to the value of the previous entry's post-change SHA1).

Unfortunately, modifying the entry results in a log that no longer accurately reflects the history of the ref.  For example, the change reason may no longer make sense after the rewrite.  This is why `--rewrite` is not the default.

Comment: Oh I see, it all makes sense now. Thanks.