# Delete git objects completely after a git reset

Tags: git

Per http://snipplr.com/view/11513/, I tried

```
$ git reflog expire --expire=1.minute refs/heads/master
$ git fsck --unreachable # now I see those tarball blobs!
$ git prune # hasta la vista, baby
$ git gc # cleanup and repack the repo
```

but it did not help, I am still able to checkout by a hash code.

Comment: Note that unless the discarded commits take a significant amount of disk space or are a security risk, you can just ignore this, and it'll take care of itself eventually.

Answer (score 3):

The commands you linked to didn't work because `git gc` doesn't prune anything less than two weeks old by default, so you need to specify that you want to prune everything:

```
git reflog expire --expire-unreachable=now
git gc --prune=now
```

The call to `git prune` is redundant, since `git gc` calls it anyway. The call to `git fsck` is only for display purposes and need not be run.

Note that these commands will make it impossible to recover any other unreachable commits, and of course the reflog will be cleared making any of its nice rollback features unusable for past history.

Comment: git reflog --expire-unreachable=now     
fatal: unrecognized argument: --expire-unreachable=now     
  
correct syntax seems to be:    
git reflog expire --expire-unreachable=now    

Unfortunately after gc I am still able to checkout by a hash code

Comment: Yup, you're right, I've updated. Do the commit hashes in question show up in `git fsck --unreachable`?

Comment: Make sure you don't have reference to that commit `git tag --contains <commit>` and `git branch -a --contains <commit>` and then repack them.

Comment: you might want to to add the `--rewrite` option to `git reflog expire`, see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9184344/git-reflog-expire-and-git-fsck-unreachable for more information on expiring stuff from the reflog

Answer (score 0):

Among other things, you'd need to also expire `HEAD`'s reflog in order for the commit to become dereferenced.

Comment: Can you please explain how to expire the HEAD's reflog?      Is it: git reflog expire --expire-unreachable=now

Comment: It'd be the same as the command for `refs/heads/master`, except using `HEAD` instead.